# C99 complex casting

Tags: c, c99, complex-numbers

I have some C99 code where I need to convert an array of 2n double to an array of n double complex.  I do this with

```
static void real_to_complex(const double *r, size_t n, double complex *z)
{
  size_t i;

  for (i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
    z[i] = r[2*i] + r[2*i + 1]*I;
}
```

This is a performance critical part of the code, and I'd really rather not have to create a new storage area z and have the expense of the copying, instead I'd like to replace these function calls by

```
z = (double complex*)r;
```

Is there any way to do this and remain standard conforming? I understand that a double complex is guaranteed to have the same layout as an array of two doubles -- perhaps I could get away with a compiler check as to whether this layout is (real,imaginary) or (imaginary,real)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are guaranteed the first element of the `complex` array corresponds to the real part and the second element corresponds to the imaginary part.

Quote from [the publicly available draft of C11 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> 6.2.5/13 Each complex type has the same representation and alignment requirements as an array type containing exactly two elements of the corresponding real type; the first element is equal to the real part, and the second element to the imaginary part, of the complex
>   number.

Example program

```
#include <complex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  double x[] = {42, 2, 41, 1, 0, 0};
  _Complex double *y = (void*)x;
  while (creal(*y) > 0) {
    printf("%f + %fi\n", creal(*y), cimag(*y));
    y++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This; simply using `(double complex *)r` is just fine.